# Hashtable Implementation

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, hashtable

I was recently asked 'how would you implement a hastable'.  I know the hashing algorithm is critical as the less collisions the better WRT performance, but what algorithm/data structure should be employed to deliver amortized constant time {O(1)} for insert/delete/lookups?

Comment: may the force of arrays be with you

Comment: Have you looked in a book, say "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen et al.?

Comment: That is exactly the book I am in the process of getting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hash tables have two main possibilities:

1. **Open Addressing**, which is a **simple array** [dynamic array actualy if you
   can let your table grow on the fly]. Once a conflict has met - you need to use a second hash function to find the next entree that the element will be mapped to. Note this solution has some troubles [which can be solved] when your hash table also allows deletions. [Special mark for "deleted" entrees]
2. **Chaining** - in this solution, each entree in the **array** is a **linked list** - containig all elements hashed to this entree. In here - all elements mapped to a certain value are in the list.

The important part about hash tables [in both solutions] in order to allow armotorized O(1) insert/del/look up - is allocating a bigger table and rehashing once a pre defined [load factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Load_factor) was reached.

**EDIT:** complexity analsis:

Assume a load factor of `p` for some `p < 1`.

1. The probability of "collision" in each access is `p` Thus the mean of array accesses is: `Sigma(i * p^(i-1) * (1-p)) for each i in [1,n]` This gives you: `Sigma(i * p^(i-1) * (1-p)) = (1-p) * Sigma(i * p^(i-1)) <= (1-p) * 1/(p-1)^2 = 1-p = CONST`. [have a look at the correctness of [Sigma(i * p^(i-1)) <  1/(p-1)^2 in wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28i%20*%20p%5E%28i-1%29%29)]. Thus resulting on average a constant number of accesses to the array. Also: You might need to rehash all elements after the load factor was reached, resulting in `O(n)` accesses to the array. This results in `n * O(1)` ops [adding n elements] and `1 * O(n)` op [rehashing], so you get: `(n * O(1) + 1 * O(n)) / n = O(1)` armotorized time.
2. Very similar to (1), but the analysis is done on list accesses. Each operation requires exactly one array accesses, and a variant number of list accesses - with the same analysis as before.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I think you've mixed up your terminology. "Chained" hash table implementations consist of linked lists of items within each hash bucket. "Open addressed" hash table implementations are the ones that store items within the one buffer, and can be implemented with the double hashing strategy that you've described. Check the page that you've linked to...

Comment: @DarrenEngwirda: Thank you for your comment. I am not a native english speaker and I do tend to mix terms from time to time because of it. I editted the answer.